# Speed up the Conversion of Tens of thousands doc to docx using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have more than 44K doc files waiting to be converted to docx. The code I used to convert a single doc file is the followings:

```
from win32com import client

def doc2docx(doc_name):
    word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    doc = word.Documents.Open(doc_name)
    docx_name = doc_name.replace(".doc", ".docx")
    doc.SaveAs(docx_name, 16)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()
```

I tried the following code to convert a subset of 10 doc documents:

```
from glob import glob
from time import time

paths = glob("U:\\WordDocuments\*.doc")
start = time()
counter = 0
for i in paths:
    doc2docx(i)
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
end = time()
duration = end -start
print("It took", duration, "seconds to process 10 doc files.")
```

The code above runs without an error. However, it took more than 3 minutes to covert 10 doc documents. How can I speed up this process? I can think of multithreading or multiprocessing but I do not know how to implement them. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know which part of your code is taking time? Wild guess, but I would say opening several words and closing them after each document might be a waste of time

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I agree.

Answer (score 1):

```
from win32com import client
from glob import glob
from time import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def doc2docx(doc_name):
    word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    doc = word.Documents.Open(doc_name)
    docx_name = doc_name.replace(".doc", ".docx")
    doc.SaveAs(docx_name, 16)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()

paths = glob("U:\\WordDocuments\*.doc")
global start
start = time()
A = []
pool = Pool()
r=pool.map_async(doc2docx,paths,callback=pool_processing_complete)
r.wait()
pool.close()
pool.join()

def pool_processing_complete(x):
    A.extend(x)
    global start
    end = time()
    duration = end -start
    print("It took", duration, "seconds to process 10 doc files.")
```

Use multiprocessing pool this is sample.

Comment: I moved pool_processing_complete() between A = [] and pool = Pool(). The code ran without stop.

Comment: @JamesChang pool process will use all cores parallel. So it might give more speed depends on your machine.

Comment: The code ran without stop even when I processed 10 doc documents. That's weird.